# Setting an environment for a codeception Acceptance Test

Tags: codeception

I've been trying out codeception for acceptance tests. I'd like to be able to set an environment to use selenium so tests that don't need javascript can use the much faster phpBrowser driver and then tests that need JS can do this:

```
$scenario->env('selenium'); 
$I = new WebGuy($scenario); 
$I->wantTo('ensure that Teacher Login works'); 
etc...
```

however when i set the env the test runs and says Acceptance tests (0)  - no tests are run.  Commenting out that line and the tests run.

```
class_name: WebGuy
modules:
    enabled:
        - PhpBrowser
        - WebHelper
        - WebDebug
    config:
        Selenium2:
          url: 'http://test.r5'
          browser: firefox
        PhpBrowser:
            url: 'http://test.r5'
env:
    selenium:
         modules:
            enabled:
                - Selenium2
            config:
                url: 'http://test.r5'
                browser: firefox
```

How can i set one acceptance test to run Selenium?

ref
http://codeception.com/docs/07-AdvancedUsage#Environments

Comment: No solution found? I've the same identical question

Comment: 'fraid not, settled for running all the tests in selenium mode for now, which is obviously sub-optimum, no matter how cool it is to see the robot opening firefox and clicking all the things... : )

Comment: I had the same problem. Only solution I found - create different configs and specify them in command line.

Comment: I'm going to dv this because it's outdated, and uses the old syntax.

Comment: However, let's also try to answer it. What command are you using to run your tests? What is the output? Is selenium server java jar up and running? What is the output from Selenium?